# Screen goes black for a while if camera orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-orientation

While changing device `orientation` from *portrait to landscape*  and *landscape to portrait* it is happening.The problem I am facing is while changing from one mode to another screen goes black for a while.It seems activity is recreated.

I used `android:configChanges` but after that programatically surface view orientation I am not able to change.

**How to avoid the black screen while changing camera mode?**

Answer (score 1):

When activity recreated it does all things you requested in `onCreate()`.

If you are using Activity then you should consider using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` for the heavy objects in your activity.

But remember `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is now deprecated.

If you are comfortable with Fragments then you should use setRetainInstance(boolean) instead.

Below links will help you.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html
[http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Fragment](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html)
http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-fragments-saving-state-and-screen-rotation/

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply.But I am not able to resolve the issue.In my manifest I have given    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation".

Comment: In surfacecreated() and surfacechange() I have given:parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);                 parameters.setRotation(90);//for portrait and angle zero for landscape.

Comment: what is device os version? if you are targetting sdk 13,then try using android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"